# How to access my user folder in CMD

Tags: cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

My Windows crashed and won't boot to login screen. I need to delete some files in order to reinstall Windows's to keep my files. (My disk is full)

My only option is to use Command prompt from repair mode to delete some files.

I'm on vacation so I have no other tools or options than CMD. All other options in repair mode didn't work.

When I type "dir" inside "X:\users" i get the following messages:

```
07/16/2016 04:13 AM    <DIR>     .
07/16/2016 04:13 AM    <DIR>     ..
07/16/2016 04:13 AM    <DIR>     Public
```

I can't see the name of my user folders, just dots. I tried to access my user folder by typing     cd , but it says     "The system cannot find the path specified".

How can I access my user folder ?

Comment: Run `bcdedit | find "osdevice"`. That should be the drive letter for your original system drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think x: is not your user hard drive letter but the letter of the ram drive used to start the recovery cmd.

You have to find on wich letter your hard drive is mounted (probably c:) and search for your user profile on this disk.

You can use diskpart to locate all the mounted volumes :

- first you run **diskpart** from the cmd prompt
- then you type **list vol**
- finally type **exit** to go back to the cmd

Comment: I have the exact problem. I'm using the repair command prompt and it says `x:\>` as the drive letter. Using `diskpart`, I do find the c drive but when I do `cd c:` or `cd \c` or `cd /c`, they all end up not working. Any suggestions?